Azure Container App - How to make client certificate available
I'm exposing an endpoint (only port 8080) via Azure Container app.
One of the first steps I'm need to do first is validate the http request client certificate.
I have the following code which locally works:
 // Attempt to get the certificate from the connection
 var clientCertificate = httpContext.Connection?.ClientCertificate;
 if (clientCertificate != null)
     return clientCertificate;

 // Check if the X-ARR-ClientCert header is present
 if (httpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("X-ARR-ClientCert", out var certHeader) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(certHeader))
 {
     try
     {
         byte[] certBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(certHeader!);
         clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certBytes);

         return clientCertificate;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         logger.LogError(ex, "Unable to parse certificate from header 'X-ARR-ClientCert'.");
     }
 }

When running locally httpContext.Connection?.ClientCertificate is enough. On an App service httpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("X-ARR-ClientCert", out var certHeader) is enough.
I have followed this and set the value to "accept".
My ACA is in side a vnet and at first i thought maybe a gateway or something was dropping the certificate but when i try the direct endpoint (from inside the vnet) I have the exact same issue.
Any ideas? Am I missing some configuration?

please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/client-certificate-authorization

That was the link i wanted to have in "this"... will update. but yes I have done that.

Azure Container Apps may not directly support X-ARR-ClientCert like App Service does, as ACA's ingress doesn’t inherently pass all headers unless configured.

Do you know where I can check this configuration to pass all headers?

Due to limitation in aca, your setup might not be passing the client certificate as expected. Can you try using nginx reverse proxy to handle TLS termination and client certificate validation

See set up mTLS on Azure Container Apps, to use NGINX as a reverse proxy.

It seems I missed some documentation from MSFT regarding header.
Is also seems I was not setting up properly postman while sending certificates.
According to documentation the header where I can see the certificate is 'X-Forwarded-Client-Cert'. I'm also adding here another link regarding the details of this header for future reference.
I do have now an issue with the certificate chain which seems to be different vs the one in the file, but this is outside of the original question.

If you need to set up mTLS on Azure Container Apps, one effective method is to use NGINX as a reverse proxy.
you’ll need three types of certificates a CA certificate, a server certificate, and a client certificate.


Now, create an NGINX configuration file (example nginx.conf)
events {}

http {
    server {
        listen 8080 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/server.key;
        ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/ca.crt;
        ssl_verify_client on;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
        }
    }
}


With the configuration ready, create Dockerfiles for both the NGINX server and your FastAPI application
for nginx
FROM nginx:stable
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY server.crt /etc/nginx/certs/server.crt
COPY server.key /etc/nginx/certs/server.key
COPY ca.crt /etc/nginx/certs/ca.crt


for the fastapi
FROM python:3.10-slim

RUN pip install fastapi uvicorn

COPY app.py /app/app.py
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8081

CMD ["uvicorn", "app:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8081"]


Now build these images, push them to your acr and then deploy them on container apps
az containerapp create \
  --name nginx-mtls-proxy \
  --resource-group your-resource-group \
  --environment your-environment \
  --image your-acr-name.azurecr.io/nginx-mtls:latest \
  --target-port 8080 \
  --ingress external \
  --registry-server your-acr-name.azurecr.io \
  --registry-identity system


Same way repeat for the fastapi


Done. This should secure your application with mTLS. Here the nginx reverse proxy validates client certificates before requests reach your application.

Thank you for the reply. STill, I feed this to be too complex, plus, this container app is also being used exactly to behave like a reverse proxy, so setting up a reverse proxy for a reverse proxy seems strange. In the end, the ACA should allow this to happen and I'm looking for that alternative.
